# pywin32 not working with PTVS

Tags: python-2.7, pywin32, canopy, ptvs

I have been playing around with PTVS 2.1 Beta 2 and Visual Studio Express 2013 with upgrade 3.  I liked a lot of the features in PTVS so I was excited to give it a try.  So far it is OK, but I have one major and confusing problem.

I am running Enthought Canopy Express 32 bit.

I rely on the pywin32 library a lot to connect to com objects.  When I tried running some of my code that uses pywin32 through PTVS it fails.  The line that fails in my code is:

```
from win32com.client import *
```

Here is the error:

```
   File "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

The weird thing is that if I just launch an interpreter window outside of visual studio (C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\python.exe) then the same code works just fine.

I started by comparing sys.path between the two approaches and they are the same.

It appears to me that the win32api.pyd file fails to load some dll that it depends on.  I opened win32api.pyd in dependency walker and with the exception of a number of deeply nested late loading dependencies, MSVCR90.DLL was the only thing that could not be located.

I tried copying this from the matplotlib\backends folder to the same folder as win32api.pyd but it did not help.  MSVCR90.DLL is NOT in windows\system or windows\sysWOW64.

I would love to use PTVS as my goto, but I'm stuck if I can't get this to work.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How did you set up your project to use Canopy as an interpreter? Did you use the PTVS integration support that they provide (where Canopy shows up as a distinct and properly named interpreter in the Python Environments window), or did you just add it as a custom interpreter?

Comment: I installed canopy with the Enthough installer and then PTVS recognized it by default (I think, but I can't remember for sure). After I posted the question I realized that it worked with no files open and didn't work when files were open.  That felt like a bug so I filed bug 2633 on the PTVS codeplex page.  Then I found the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.  Another install of VS 2013 for web was interfering some how.  I un-installed it and the problem went away.